# sklearn LabelEncoder inverse_transform TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Tags: scikit-learn, python-3.6

I am getting the following error when calling the inverse_transform of LabelEncoder:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 31, in <module>
    inverted = label_encoder.inverse_transform(integer_encoded['DEST'])
  File "...\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 283, in inverse_transform
    return self.classes_[y]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index
```

The code that generates this error is the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import defaultdict
from sklearn import preprocessing
import bisect
data_cat = {'ORG': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'],
            'DEST': ['A', 'E', 'F', 'G'],
            'OP': ['F1', 'F1', 'F1', 'F2']}
data_cat = pd.DataFrame(data_cat)

#retain all columns LabelEncoder as dictionary.
label_encoder_dict = defaultdict(preprocessing.LabelEncoder) 
integer_encoded = data_cat.apply(lambda x: label_encoder_dict[x.name].fit_transform(x))
print("Integer encoded: ")
print(integer_encoded)

#add a UNK class that will be used for the unseen values from the test dataset
for key, le in label_encoder_dict.items():
    le_classes = np.array(le.classes_).tolist()
    bisect.insort_left(le_classes, 'UNK')
    le.classes_ = le_classes

label_encoder = label_encoder_dict['DEST']
print(label_encoder.classes_)
print(integer_encoded['DEST'])
print(type (integer_encoded['DEST']))
inverted = label_encoder.inverse_transform(integer_encoded['DEST'])
print(inverted)
```

If I remove the for loop that adds the UNK class to every LabelEncoder, everything is working fine. I don't understand why adding a new class impacts the call of the inverse_transform.

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Comment: Can you provide more context on the error message? That doesn't really give enough to be helpful

Comment: I have added some details, no sure is helpful enough. Thanks.

Comment: You need to inverse_transform with the OneHotEncoder before you can inverse_transform with the LabelEncoder

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I have also tried to call the invert_transform of LabelEncoder on the integer_encode, so before calling the OneHotEncode and I get the same error : inverted = label_encoder.inverse_transform(integer_encoded['DEST'])
The type of integer_encoded['DEST'] is : Name: DEST, dtype: int32
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Comment: I imagine that would work. Does it?

Comment: It does not, I get the same error.

Comment: Try using integer_encoded['DEST'].values

Comment: inverted = label_encoder.inverse_transform(integer_encoded['DEST'].values)
  File ..Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\sklearn\preprocessing\label.py", line 283, in inverse_transform
    return self.classes_[y]
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

Comment: If you remove your `integer_encoded = integer_encoded.as_matrix(integer_encoded.columns)` line, try doing `label_encoder_dict['DEST'].inverse_transform(integer_encoded['DEST'])`

Comment: Yes, it’s what I did. I’m calling the LabelEncoder invert_transform before calling oh=OneHotEncoder...

Comment: Yes, but does that exact line of code work or fail?

Comment: it does not, same error

Comment: If you can provide more code/sample data, I could help you more. I tried the same steps on some other data and it worked fine for me.

Comment: indeed, on another simple dataset is working for me too. It must be a stupid error I don't mange to see here. Thanks, i'll search more.

Comment: I have updated the description with a code that reproduce exactly the error. The error appears only if I have the for loop to add a new class to the LabelEncoder. I did not put it in my initial code as I was expected at all to be related to the problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LabelEncoder.inverse_transform` is actually quite simple. The LabelEncoder object stores an array of original values in the `classes_` attribute, and the encoded integer is the index of that value in `classes_`. Normally, `classes_` is an `np.array` type which supports passing a list of indices to get the values at those indices. However, in your for loop you converted that to a regular old python list, which does not support that behavior.

If you change your for loop to keep `le.classes_` as an ndarray, it should work:

```
for key, le in label_encoder_dict.items():
    le_classes = np.array(le.classes_).tolist()
    bisect.insort_left(le_classes, 'UNK')
    le.classes_ = np.asarray(le_classes)
```

Comment: Although, I don't really understand what the purpose of the new category is. If you attempt to encode an unknown value, it won't default to 'UNK', and you can only inverse_transform to 'UNK' if the value is `len(le.classes_)-1`

Comment: When calling transform for the test dataset, each unknown value is replaced by "UNK"
`for i, colN in  enumerate(cols_ToOneHot):
    le = label_encoder_dict[colN]
    function = np.vectorize(lambda s: self.unkSymb if s not in le.classes_ else s)
    data_cat.iloc[:, i] = np.apply_along_axis(function, 0 , data_cat.iloc[:,i])
    data_cat.iloc[:, i] = le.transform(data_cat.iloc[:,i]) `
Are there better ways to handled the unseen values in transform?

Comment: You could consider looking at the source code for LabelEncoder to see how they handle it. Consider using a set rather than an array or a list when seeing if your value is in le.classes_, since it is faster to check for inclusion in a set than in a list/array.

Comment: Alternatively, you could extend LabelEncoder, and overwrite _encode_numpy and _encode_python to set the value to your unknown value, instead of raising a ValueError. https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/bac89c2/sklearn/preprocessing/label.py